# Getting Sqlitelog (23) not authorized error while select query in phonegap android.....

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am creating an app in which I have executing an select to get the access rights an base on the rights i want to run another select query. But while doing this its giving me (23) not authorized error in the logcat.

```
var checkAccessQuery = "select * from ug_access where ug_id = '"+window.localStorage.getItem("roleId")+
                     "' and f_id = "+window.localStorage.getItem("module_id")+" and comp_code = "+window.localStorage.getItem('companyCode')+"";
 var query1 = '';
var moduleId ='';
var pkId ='';
$(function(tx){
 db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(checkAccessQuery,[],function(tx,results){
        var dataset = results.rows.length;
        if(dataset>0)
        {

        }else{
            window.localStorage.setItem('accessDenied',true);
            window.location.href = 'home.html';
        }
        console.log('value in module_id: '+window.localStorage.getItem('module_Id'));
        window.localStorage.setItem('sessionModuleId',window.localStorage.getItem('module_Id'));
        var innerModule  = 0;
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('innerModule') != 'undefined' || window.localStorage.getItem('innerModule') !=''  )
        {
            innerModule = window.localStorage.getItem('innerModule');
        }
        moduleId = 0;
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('module_Id') != 'undefined' || window.localStorage.getItem('module_Id') != '' )
        {
            moduleId = window.localStorage.getItem('module_Id');
        }
        pkId = 0;
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('pkIdDelete') != 'undefined' || window.localStorage.getItem('pkIdDelete') != '')
        {
            pkId = window.localStorage.getItem('pkIdDelete');
        }

        if(pkId !=0)
                {
tx.executeSql('select * from user_form',[],function(tx,result){
var dataset = result.rows.length;
console.log('length of the dynamic_form: '+dataset);
});
        }
    });
 },errorCb,sucessCb);


});
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem.
Any Idea is appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: neerav i faced same issue and solved...can you explain what the above code does...

Comment: Aravinth when first  executes in its results we check for pkId ifs its not null then second query is execute to fetch the result from the users table so i may need to execute few more query in the above function to finally create a  delete query dynamically.

Comment: ok now comment this   window.location.href = 'home.html'; in else part then run..

Comment: ok now it didn't give this error but can you tell what happen exactly..

Comment: yep...good..when we call external page the current page elements are not called so the query shown the error.you can solve this.

Comment: so can you tell me how can i solve this bcz if the result is 0 it should go to the home page.....

Comment: i will post as a answer its useful for like me and you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution for solving sqlite 23 not authorized error.

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
tx.executeSql(checkAccessQuery,[],function(tx,results){
    var dataset = results.rows.length;
    if(dataset>0)
    {

    }else{
        window.localStorage.setItem('accessDenied',true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = 'home.html';
        }, 1500);

    }
});
```