# Error (23) not authorized in websql

Tags: android, cordova, web-sql

I am creating a phoneagap mobile application, and want to use WebSql to store data in local storage.

so I am following this one...

[Create Android App with SQLite using Phonegap + Jquery mobile](http://luthfihariz.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/android-sqlite-phonegap-jquerymobile/)

I have successfully created table, but when I call executeSql() method on a button click , It gives error (23) not authorized.

I am using phonegap 3.5.0-0.20.4 version. which is latest, running on android 4.2.2,
How Can I resolver this problem, what is exact problem is???

Here is my code :-

Firstly I have register a deviceReady listener and create a db using

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db = window.openDatabase("abc_db", "1.0", "The ABC", 200000);
```

then

```
     function onDeviceReady(){
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
     }

        //create table and insert some record
        function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authentication (company_name TEXT NOT NULL, company_engineer TEXT NOT NULL, company_project TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Authentication(company_name, company_engineer, company_project, password) VALUES ("Company 1", "Engineer 1", "Project 1", "1111")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Authentication(company_name, company_engineer, company_project, password) VALUES ("Company 2", "Engineer 2", "Project 2", "2222")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Authentication(company_name, company_engineer, company_project, password) VALUES ("Company 3", "Engineer 3", "Project 3", "3333")');
        }

        //function will be called when an error occurred
        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        //function will be called when process succeed
        function successCB() {
            alert("success!");                
        }
```

then on a button click I am using...

```
funcion doLogin(){
          password = document.forms["login"]["passowrd"].value;
          company_name = document.forms["login"]["company"].value;
          company_engineer = document.forms["login"]["company_engineer"].value;
          company_project = document.forms["login"]["company_project"].value;

          db = window.openDatabase("abc_db", "1.0", "The ABC", 200000);
          db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
      }

function queryDB(tx){
               var qry = "SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE company_name = '" + company_name + "' AND company_engineer = '" + company_engineer + "' AND company_project = '" + company_project + "' AND `password` = '" + password + "'";

               tx.executeSql(qry ,[],querySuccess, errorGet);
           }

 function querySuccess(tx, result){
                if(result.rows.length !== 0){
                    document.location.href = 'home.html';
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid Username or password');
                }

           }
```

Comment: comment the `document.location.href = 'home.html';` in button click and try now.

Comment: check this answer and question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080534/getting-sqlitelog-23-not-authorized-error-while-select-query-in-phonegap-andro/23081906#23081906

Comment: @Aravin, Thanks for reply, I have tried both but not working....

Comment: can you tell me what are you trying when button is clicked. I faced similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672814/canvas-signature-touch-creates-issue-in-phonegap

Comment: @Aravin I want to select data from database to check that user is authorized or not< I have insert data in table at starting point by calling db.transction() in onDeviceReady().

Comment: when you get the  sqlite error insert data or select data.

Comment: I get error on select data, even I have successfully select data if I  do it on onDeviceReady() function. But according to my requirments I have to do it on form submit, That's generate the error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56333/discussion-between-aravin-and-roy).

Comment: @Aravin Thanks dude, I have found finally a solution, Actually the form is not submit in a good manner, Now I have submit form using Jquery like `$('#form').submit(function(){});` and problem resolved.